# How do I organise UICollectionViewCells according the server data they are storing?

Tags: ios, database, api, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have cells which display images that a user has taken and added to the `UICollectionView`. On the API server, these images are organised by the `timestamp` (see below), which means that in the app, the first cell displayed is the most recent image uploaded to the server.

On the server, it looks like this:

```
results: [
{
i_id: "28",
title: "image title",
description: "Picture",
longitude: "0.000000",
latitude: "0.000000",
filename: "http://server.com/images/image.jpg",
timestamp: "12:34:04",
n_likes: "0",
n_comments: "1",
images: {

}
},

{
i_id: "21",
title: "another image title"
description: "another Picture",
longitude: "0.000000",
latitude: "0.000000",
filename: "http://server.com/images/image.jpg",
timestamp: "12:20:49",
image: "",
n_likes: "2",
n_comments: "4",
images: {

}
}
]
```

I am able to get each image’s `n_comments` data into an array without problems. I want the array to count the number at each object at index and determine which would be displayed in the `UICollectionView` first, according to the number that the object contains (if that makes sense).

Would this be something that I’d have to manage on the server, or can I do it within the app’s code? I’m guessing that it has to do with `UICollectionViewLayout`, so that’s where I’ll be attempting to get it to work in the meantime.

Any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this on either end, but you don't need to do anything with UICollectionViewFlowLayout. On the app end, you could sort your array with sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: with a descriptor of sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:, passing n_comments as the key.

Comment: I decided to make the alterations server side as it was an unnecessarily large task to perform within the app.